# Java FileChannel bigger than its content

Tags: java, filechannel

I am creating a fileChannel to perform memory mapped writing. This fileChannel has a size of 100 bytes. I only write 80 bytes to it. So when I read from that file later on, it adds 5 "0" to the and. Is there any way to set the size or get the size which is written to the file?

Thanks a lot!!

```
public FileChannel create(String randomFile){
   // create file output stream
   RandomAccessFile raf;
   FileChannel fc = null;

   try {    
      raf = new RandomAccessFile(randomFile, "rw");
      fc = raf.getChannel();
      System.out.println("fc.size() "+ fc.size());      
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return fc;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `FileChannel.open()`?

Comment: I use the FileChannel to create a MappedByteBuffer.`mbb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, position, bufferSize);` and then write to that buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("thefile");
final FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
    StandardOpenOption.READ);

// then later:

fc.truncate(80L);
```

And of course, don't forget to `.close()`. And ideally you should open your channel using a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: I get this error, when doing this: The method open(Path, OpenOption...) in the type FileChannel is not applicable for the arguments (Path, FileChannel.MapMode)

Comment: Ah, well, a quick look at the javadoc should have told you what's wrong, and even the error in fact. Replace `FileChannel.MapMode.WRITE` with `StandardOpenOption.WRITE`.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. Now I get the problem that I cannot map the file to memory: `MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, position, bufferSize);`This throws a nonReadableChannel Exception, I don't know why...

Comment: Well, you did specify that you wanted to open it for write but not read; add `StandardOpenOption.READ` as an open option, that should do it

Comment: The truncate does the job I needed, it reduces the size to the written amount. I wasn't aware of this method. How the file is opened actually doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, I also had the same problem and `truncate()` helped. But do you have a reason why `FileChannel` allocates a bigger file than needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think `setLength()` is what you're looking for.  [Java doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength(long))

Comment: this one returns 100 bytes as well. Before I start writing to the file.